# Remove last n days from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with datetime index (30 min frequency). And I want do remove "n" last days from it. My dataframe do not include weekends, so if the last day of it is Monday, I want to remove Monday, Friday and Thursday (from the end). So, I mean observed days, not calendar. What is the most pythonic way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter pandas dataframe for past x days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192704/filter-pandas-dataframe-for-past-x-days)

Comment: Not quite. In that topic they are speaking about calendar days. In my situation I want to remove last observed days, not calendat. Thnx

Answer (score 2):

Pandas knows about Monday to Friday as business days.

So if you want to remove the last n business days from your dataframe, you can just do:

```
df.drop(df[df.index >= df.index.max().date()-pd.offsets.BDay(n-1)].index, inplace=True)
```

---

If you really need to remove *observed* days in the dataframe, if will be slightly more complex because you will have to count the days. Code could be (using a companion dataframe called `df_days`):

```
# create a dataframe with same index and only one row per day:
df_days = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index).assign(day=df.index.date).drop_duplicates('day')
# now count the observed day in the companion dataframe
df_days['new_day'] = 1
df_days['days'] = df_days['new_day'].cumsum()
# compute first index to remove to remove last observed n days
ix = df_days.loc[df_days['days'] == df_days['days'].max() + 1 - n].index[0]

# ok drop the last observed n days from the initial dataframe and delete the companion one
df.drop(df.loc[df.index > ix].index)
del df_days
```

Comment: Thank you so much!